# Magento not able to add multiple items in single wishlist EE 1.14

Tags: magento-enterprise, wishlist

I'm not able to add multiple items in a single wishlist, if I add a new item on same wishlist, it is replaced by previous item.

I'm using `Magento EE 1.14.0.1` , Please help me to solve this issue, to my knowledge this appears to be a bug?

Comment: what code are you using to add items to the wishlist?

Comment: i'm not using any external code, i just install fresh magento 1.14 with sample db . In product details page i'm able to add only one item in a wishlist.

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue for EE1.14. Magento has fixed this in 1.14.1. You can find this in the release notes here - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-later-release-notes (just search for 'Resolved the following issues with the wish list:' on that page).

Comment: Thanks Bhalin Ramabhadran, I was created a module for multiple wishlist.